# Proving a set to be countably infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asked to decide and prove whether the set $\{\,x\in\mathbb{N}: |x-7|>|x|\,\}$ is finite, infinitely countable, or uncountable.

I'm pretty certain it is infinitely countable. I say that since the set is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, that the set is countable. 
Now, I need to prove it to be infinite. I'm having trouble. Would the best way to go about it be to suppose that it's finite, then find a contradiction?

Answer (score 4):

If $x\ge 7$ then $|x-7|=x-7$, and of course $|x|=x$. Hence any $x\in \mathbb N$ with $x\ge 7$ is certainly not in your set ($x-7\not>x$), making it finite.

Comment: Oops, it was supposed to be a less than sign!

Comment: So, then it seems like the set is clearly finite and only contains {0, 1, 2, 3} ?

Comment: Hm, check again, I hope the signs are now right and the ones you have in your actual problem statement?